# Java save and restore frame positions, sizes, and states

Tags: c#, java, swing, settings, frame

In C# .NET there is a built in **[Settings.settings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rprabhu/archive/2005/11/28/497792.aspx)** file that allow to easily store form related properties such as positions, sizes, and states at user level.

Is there something similar in Java ? Whats the best way to save and restore frame related settings in Java ?

Comment: Use Preferences class as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017137/how-do-i-save-preference-user-settings-in-java

Comment: regarding the specific requirement of saving and restoring **UI states**, you may want to take a look at GUTS-GUI SessionManager (http://guts.kenai.com/guts-base/guts-gui/apidocs/net/guts/gui/session/package-summary.html#package_description). This requires Guice, but I believe the code can be easily adapted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html)** API can help you in this regard.

> Applications require preference and configuration data to adapt to the needs of different users and environments. The `java.util.prefs package` provides a way for applications to store and retrieve user and system preference and configuration data. The data is stored persistently in an implementation-dependent backing store. There are two separate trees of preference nodes, one for user preferences and one for system preferences.