# User preferences

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, final

I want to make a simple java program that creates a text file at somewhere. I want to let users choose the folder. But when I wrap it in jar file and send to others. Every time my friend runs it, it asks for the folder. I wonder how I can let the jar file only asks once and set it as final. 
Inside my .java file, I have something like

```
public void setDefaultFolder() {
    //initially path is empty string
    if(fc.getPath().equals("")){
        String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please select a default folder." +
                " Make sure it exists and it's not changeable once set");
        if(a != null) {
        String b = a.replace("\\","\\\\");
        // set String path = something users enter
        // fc is a helper object. I have all the read/write file or other methods 
        // there. I want to let the jar file read the path only for the first time
        // and set the path final, later on, when it detects path is not empty
        // string, it stops asking users to type in path.
        fc.setPath(b);
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Folder not set");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Save it in a configuration file. If the configuration file exists, read the path. If not, ask for it and save it.

Comment: How to I add some if statement, if it is empty, the I want to let execute that JOpitionPane.showInputDialog. If it's not empty, then I am not executing the input dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the users configuration somewhere. There is many ways to do this, for example you can use java.util.prefs package, as stated by Peter Knego in his [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017137/how-do-i-save-preference-user-settings-in-java):

```
// Retrieve the user preference node for the package com.mycompany
Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(com.mycompany.MyClass.class);

// Preference key name
final String PREF_NAME = "name_of_preference";

// Set the value of the preference
String newValue = "a string";
prefs.put(PREF_NAME, newValue);

// Get the value of the preference;
// default value is returned if the preference does not exist
String defaultValue = "default string";
String propertyValue = prefs.get(PREF_NAME, defaultValue); // "a string"
```

Comment: Do I have to create a new class?

Comment: No, check this out, might help you out:
http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/simple-java-preferences-api-example

Comment: How to I add some if statement, if it is empty, the I want to let execute that JOpitionPane.showInputDialog. If it's not empty, then I am not executing the input dialog.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use a properties file to store the folder location. you would then load the property every time the jar loads

Comment: suggest you check out...[props useage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) and [props example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)