# How do I decreased by 1 per day the all of number value on one column every day automatically?

Tags: java, netbeans

This is my table

Sample(tablename)
-Day_start(column1)
-Day_end(column2)
-Total_days(column3)
-Days_left(column4)

Day_start(column1)
-March 1 2017(data)

Day_end(column2)
-April 5 2017(data)

Total_days(column3)
-36 (data)

days_left(column4)
-36(data)

Sorry for my last question, im not good in English!.. So this is my question In the day of  March 2 2017 the days left must be 35. so everyday the days_left will decrease automatically I only know the code of between two dates whichis my total_days. But I dont know how to decrease it by 1 automatically per day . Then it will diplay in the table of netbeans

Comment: Are you asking how to persist / store your label's value?

Comment: Example the jlabel has a text of 24 then tomorrow the text should be 23 automatically

Comment: Give more details how your program works. Running 24 hours a day without closing? Or launch every day?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I save preference user settings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017137/how-do-i-save-preference-user-settings-in-java)

Comment: I did get the *user story* from your question - you need to tell us what your specific *programming problem* is. We don't know if your problem is storing the current value closing the application or determining if you need to decrement your value on application startup (Closing and opening the application several time on one day).

Comment: I edit my question

Answer (score 1):

well you can *store the current date somewhere in a file*. then when the program runs again you can compare the date from the file with the current data, finally create a function to find the diffrence in days since the program was last opened. *you can als just print the date it was last opened.*